# EXCEL if cell has value move row from table to another table

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-2013, vba

I'm working on an exel template (a to do list), and for quite a while I'm stuck on 1 last issue. 
(This is just a part of the template)

[image: Example]

If a task is completed, I want to change the status to Completed (by a drop down list).

Now if a cell from the Status row has the value 'Completed', I want it to move the whole table row to another table where all the completed values are.

Does anyone know if this is possible, and if yes, a little clue on how?

You would be gratefull,

Yours Sincere,
A.

---

EDIT:

I've done everything in regards of EXCEL if cell has value move row from table to another table

Now I want on the end of my code that my table 'applies the sort' again. So there are already custom sort rules written, and I just want to re-sort my table.

I think of 2 solutions:

Go to the table and

Execute Ctrl + Alt + l

(This is to re-apply the current sort setting)

Write in VBA to sort the table again. But this without writing my sort rules again because it's 1 big complicated thing.
I searched for it, tried it myself, but I just can't get it done. I've already written a lot of code for the first part. And everything is up and running, I only need this 1 last modification to make my to-do list perfect.

Anybody has a clue?

Yours sincere, ASS

Comment: yes, it is possible. Searched a bit in stackoverflow, and found this as a primary inspiration (stackoverflow.com/questions/24632623/move-row-to-another-worksheet-where-cell-equals-worksheet-name) you can find your own solution on watching for the change event of a cell range (see this SO question stackoverflow.com/questions/409434/automatically-execute-an-excel-macro-on-a-cell-change), and write some code to move a row from one sheet to another () and test test test. If you have a more specific problem come back with your code and we will happily help you on solving it.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've coded all most everything but there is 1 more last (strange) issue. I'll keep looking and trying to find the answer and then I'll post my answer :)

Comment: Everything is up and running except this 1 last thing. Edited the post for my problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is all my code it took to make the solution. I know it looks like a lot, and that there could be an easier way but it's what it is. If there are any comments feel free to give some advice :)

(This was my first time using VBA)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim lstObj As ListObject
    Dim rColumn As Range

    ' get the table reference
    Set lstObj = Worksheets("Daily Task List").ListObjects("TaskList")

    'get the column reference
    Set rColumn = lstObj.ListColumns("Status").DataBodyRange

    'test (display first data value in the column)
    'MsgBox rColumn(1).Value

    If Not Intersect(Target, rColumn) Is Nothing Then MoveMacro (lstObj)
End Sub
```

My subroutine after the event

```
Public Sub MoveMacro(lstObj)
    'lstObj is the table reference
    If Not IsNull(lstObj) Then

        ResortTable

        If (ActiveCell.Value = "Completed") Then
            Dim SheetToPaste As String
            SheetToPaste = "CompletedSheet"

            'Remember the row that is activated for later
            Dim rng As Range
            Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 5), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 11))

            'Copy the range
            rng.Copy

            'Activate second Worksheet + First cell
            Worksheets(SheetToPaste).Activate
            ActivateFirstBlankCellInTable

            'Paste the row based on the selection (last subroutine)
            Selection.PasteSpecial

            'Ask the user if it wants the range to be deleted
            DeleteFromRow rng

            'ActivateSheet1 again
            Worksheets("Daily Task List").Activate

            'Resort the table
            ResortTable
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Activate the first cell in the blank table

```
Public Sub ActivateFirstBlankCellInTable()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    'loop through each cell untill you find empty cell
    For Each cell In ws.Columns(1).Cells
        If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then cell.Select: Exit For
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Delete range from table

```
Public Sub DeleteFromRow(rng As Range)
    If Not IsNull(rng) Then
        Dim YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox As String
        Dim QuestionToMessageBox As String

        QuestionToMessageBox = "The row will be copied to this table." & vbNewLine & "Do you want it to be deleted in the other table?"

        'promp a yes no messagebox to ask the user what it wants
        YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox = MsgBox(QuestionToMessageBox, vbYesNo, "Delete row or not")

        'Catch the reply (only yes necessary
        If YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox = vbYes Then
             rng.Delete
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Error passing range"
    End If
End Sub
```

Resort the Table (Main code)

```
Public Sub ResortTable()
    'Check if cell is in table range
    If IsActiveCellInTable = False Then
        'If not move 1 cell above
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
    End If

    'Execute Sort
    sortExecute
End Sub
```

Check if active cell is in table

```
Function IsActiveCellInTable() As Boolean
    'Function returns true if active cell is in a table and
    'false if it isn't.
    Dim rngActiveCell
    Set rngActiveCell = ActiveCell

    Debug.Print IsActiveCellInTable
    'Test for table.
    'Statement produces error when active cell is not
    'in a table.
    On Error Resume Next
    rngActiveCell = (rngActiveCell.ListObject.Name <> "")
    On Error GoTo 0
    'Set function's return value.
    IsActiveCellInTable = rngActiveCell

End Function
```

Execute the sort

```
Public Sub sortExecute()
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TaskList").AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Daily Task List").ListObjects("TaskList").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Thank you for your help on getting me started, was a nice thing being busy with VBA.

Greetings,